# Como retornar nomes de pilotos em tabela SQL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, select, join

Tenho as seguintes tabelas abaixo, e gostaria de retornar apenas o nome dos pilotos que nunca participaram de uma prova em um circuito brasileiro no pais `brasil`.

Estrutura da Tabela:

```
PAIS (id, sigla, nome)

EQUIPE (id, nome, pais_id)
pais_id referencia PAIS

PILOTO(id, nome, equipe_id, pais_id, dt_nascimento)
pais_id referencia PAIS
equipe_id referencia EQUIPE

CIRCUITO (id, nome, pais_id)
pais_id referencia PAIS

PROVA (id, data, duracao, circuito_id, numero_voltas)
circuito_id referencia CIRCUITO

RESULTADO (prova_id, piloto_id, posicao)
prova_id referencia PROVA
piloto_id referencia PILOTO
```

Valores SQL:

```
insert into pais (id,sigla, nome) values (1,'gbr', 'inglaterra');
insert into pais (id,sigla, nome) values (2,'bra', 'brasil');
insert into pais (id,sigla, nome) values (3,'ale', 'alemanha');
insert into pais (id,sigla, nome) values (4,'ita', 'itália');
insert into pais (id,sigla, nome) values (5,'esp', 'espanha');
insert into pais (id,sigla, nome) values (6,'sui', 'suica');
insert into pais (id,sigla, nome) values (7,'aus', 'austrália');
insert into pais (id,sigla, nome) values (8,'sue', 'suécia');
insert into pais (id,sigla, nome) values (9,'mex', 'méxico');

insert into equipe (id, pais_id, nome) values (1, 1, 'ferrari');
insert into equipe (id, pais_id, nome) values (2, 2, 'mercedes');
insert into equipe (id, pais_id, nome) values (3, 3, 'sauber');
insert into equipe (id, pais_id, nome) values (4, 4, 'williams');
insert into equipe (id, pais_id, nome) values (5, 5, 'red bull');
insert into equipe (id, pais_id, nome) values (6, 6, 'maclaren');
insert into equipe (id, pais_id, nome) values (7, 7, 'force india');
insert into equipe (id, pais_id, nome) values (8, 8, 'toro rosso');
insert into equipe (id, pais_id, nome) values (9, 9, 'haas');

insert into piloto (id, equipe_id, pais_id, nome, dt_nascimento) values (5, 1,  1, 'sebastian vettel', current_date - 1024);
insert into piloto (id, equipe_id, pais_id, nome, dt_nascimento) values (44, 2, 3, 'lewis hamilton', current_date - 6000);
insert into piloto (id, equipe_id, pais_id, nome, dt_nascimento) values (19, 4, 2, 'felipe massa', current_date - 5030);
insert into piloto (id, equipe_id, pais_id, nome, dt_nascimento) values (12, 3, 2, 'felipe nasr', current_date - 2048);
insert into piloto (id, equipe_id, pais_id, nome, dt_nascimento) values (14, 6, 5, 'fernando alonso', current_date - 1236);
insert into piloto (id, equipe_id, pais_id, nome, dt_nascimento) values (6, 2,  6, 'nico rosberg', current_date - 5100);
insert into piloto (id, equipe_id, pais_id, nome, dt_nascimento) values (3, 5,  7, 'daniel ricardo', current_date - 6000);
insert into piloto (id, equipe_id, pais_id, nome, dt_nascimento) values (27, 5, 8, 'nico hulkenberg', current_date - 7000);
insert into piloto (id, equipe_id, pais_id, nome, dt_nascimento) values (9, 3,  9, 'marcus ericsson', current_date - 8000);
insert into piloto (id, equipe_id, pais_id, nome, dt_nascimento) values (55, 8, 1, 'carlos sainz jr.', current_date - 6000);
insert into piloto (id, equipe_id, pais_id, nome, dt_nascimento) values (11, 7, 2, 'sergio perez', current_date - 4056);

insert into circuito(id, pais_id, nome) values (1, 5, 'melbourne');
insert into circuito(id, pais_id, nome) values (2, 3, 'interlagos');

insert into prova (id,data, circuito_id, duracao, numero_voltas) values (1,to_date('15-03-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'), 1, '01:30:12'::interval,50);

insert into resultado (prova_id, piloto_id, posicao) values (1, 44, 1);
insert into resultado (prova_id, piloto_id, posicao) values (1, 6, 2);
insert into resultado (prova_id, piloto_id, posicao) values (1, 5, 3);
insert into resultado (prova_id, piloto_id, posicao) values (1, 19, 4);
insert into resultado (prova_id, piloto_id, posicao) values (1, 12, 5);
insert into resultado (prova_id, piloto_id, posicao) values (1, 3, 6);
insert into resultado (prova_id, piloto_id, posicao) values (1, 27, 7);
insert into resultado (prova_id, piloto_id, posicao) values (1, 9, 8);
insert into resultado (prova_id, piloto_id, posicao) values (1, 55, 9);
insert into resultado (prova_id, piloto_id, posicao) values (1, 11, 10);
```

Qual seria o comando em SQL para realizar essa consulta?

Comment: Infelizmente na sua estrutura não há ligação entre a equipe e a prova ou circuito em que houve participação, impossibilitando a obtenção da informação que você deseja

Comment: @Sorack atualizei a pergunta, esqueci de por algumas informações que julguei erroneamente irrelevantes.

Comment: Está faltando a estrutura da tabela `equipe` e `resultado`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a cláusula `NOT EXISTS` para verificar as ocorrências para aquele piloto em provas no Brasil:

```
SELECT p.nome
  FROM piloto p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM resultado r
                         INNER JOIN prova p ON p.id = r.prova_id
                         INNER JOIN circuito c ON c.id = p.circuito_id
                         INNER JOIN pais pa ON pa.id = c.pais_id
                   WHERE r.piloto_id = p.id
                     AND pa.nome = 'brasil')
```

> [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-subquery.html)
>
> ... The subquery is evaluated to determine whether it returns any rows. If it returns at least one row, the result of EXISTS is "true"; if the subquery returns no rows, the result of EXISTS is "false".

Em tradução livre:

> ... A subquery é avaliada para determinar se irá retornar alguma linha. Se retornar pelo menos uma linha, o resultado do EXISTS é "verdadeiro"; se a subquery não retornar nenhuma linha, o resultado do EXISTS é "falso".

A utilização do `NOT` na frente do `EXISTS` irá inverter a sua função, retornando as linhas que não possuem valor para a `subquery` informada.

Comment: Nesse caso você vai saber quais pilotos nunca ganharam uma prova no Brasil, mas creio que seja isso que o dono da pergunta quer.

Comment: @FabianoLothor negativo. As informações da tabela `resultado` não contém apenas os pilotos ganhadores, como pode ser evidenciado pela coluna `posicao`. Então o resultado dessa `query` trará apenas os que nunca participaram e não os que nunca ganharam

Comment: Verdade @Sorack, eu havia "lido" a coluna resultado como se fosse apenas uma tabela com os ganhadores.